Sum a row in Excel with #NUM! values
I need to calculate running totals of sum events. The "score" calculations are nested if functions that will return #NUM! until values are placed in the distance columns. The total column represents a running total.
Sample image of workbook

This is the nested IF() function that is returning a #NUM! unless numbers are inputted.
=IF(G5=LARGE(G$5:G$16,1),35,
  IF(G5=LARGE(G$5:G$16,2),30,
  IF(G5=LARGE(G$5:G$16,3),25,
  IF(G5=LARGE(G$5:G$16,4),20,
  IF(G5=LARGE(G$5:G$16,5),15,0)))))

I've tried setting the Total with SUM(), SUMIF() with the middle value >0, i've tried SUMIF() disregarding NA, but I can't seem to find the right formula to do a running total and ignore the #NUM! values.
SUM with Nest If and IF NA


Use AGGREGATE() function which has capability to ignore errors. Your screenshot doesn't make sense which are input and which are desired result.

Thank you! I think I solved it by adding a =ifblank(cell, 0, nested ifs)

If I have understood correctly, you are probably looking for a running total by ignoring the multiple error values for each column per row wise, if so could try using the following formula:


• Formula used in cell L3
=SCAN(0,LET(δ, CHOOSECOLS(B3:K7,SEQUENCE(,10/2,2,2)), 
  BYROW(IF(ISERROR(δ),0,δ),SUM)),SUM)


NOTE: The above Excel Formula exclusively works with MS365 Office Insiders Version, and doesn't uses LAMBDA() construct hence its called as ETA LAMBDA(), for without Office Insiders version could try the following one:
=TAKE(SCAN(0,LET(δ, CHOOSECOLS(B3:K7,SEQUENCE(,10/2,2,2)), 
  IF(ISERROR(δ),0,δ)),LAMBDA(r,c,r+c)),,-1)


Please ensure to adapt the cell references and ranges accordingly as per your suit.

